# Dynamic UITextView Size (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift

I want size a UITextView dynamically to its contents by restricting both its width and its height to some maximums.

In particular, the textView should have a minimum width and height if there is little data (e.g., "Lorem").  As the data grows (e.g., "Lorem ipsum") it should expand in width as until it hits the maximum width ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit"), and then expand in height until it hits that maximum height.  Once it goes beyond the max width and height it should become scrollable.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So far, I am struggling to get just the height working.  I have experimented with a number of methods and, while this seemed the simplest and most promising, it just crashes.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView ) {                
    resizeTextView(txtview1)                
}


@IBOutlet weak var txtViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

func resizeTextView(_ textView: UITextView ) {        
    let minHeight: CGFloat = 20.0
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = 40.0
    txtViewHeight.constant = min(maxHeight, max(minHeight, textView.contentSize.height))
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

So, I changed the resize function to this - which kinda, sorta, sometimes works (sometimes the values show up in the text field, sometimes it doesn't display at all, sometimes the spacing within the text field is different):

```
func resizeTextView(_ textView: UITextView ) {
    
    let currentHeight = textView.contentSize.height
    let minHeight: CGFloat = 20.0
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = 40.0
       
    if currentHeight > maxHeight {
        textView.frame.size.height = currentHeight
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
    } 
    else if currentHeight < minHeight {
        textView.frame.size.height = minHeight
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    } 
    else {
        textView.frame.size.height = currentHeight
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

 }
```

I know this question has been asked an answered a dozen or more times, but none of the solutions are working for me (the above being two of the half dozen or more I have tried).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to achieve this with Timer.

You solution above is that, UITextView's delegate methods triggers your height changing method.

Your changing method affects the UITextView's delegate method under the hood.

---

In other words, it is weird that you observe UITextView's property, then do something and affect the UITextView's property,

then the observation triggers again.

---

to achieve this with Timer, then the height changing events is from your timer source, not from Apple's UIKit

- start editing, timer run
- end editing, timer gone

Comment: That should certainly stop the event being triggered twice - I like that!  But I am more focused right now on getting the textview to size properly.